# Array mask boundary given by polar equation

Tags: python, mask

I have the following polar equation: `r(theta) = R + a*Sin(n*theta)` which makes this kind of plot (for which I have used `R=1`, `a=0.1`, and `n=5`):

[image]

I want to end up with a 2D Cartesian array which is `0` inside this boundary, and `1` outisde of it (red pen marks).

Does anyone know of an "elegant" and simple way to do this?

My attempts so far (and ongoing) are just trying to convert a polar meshgrid to a cartesian grid...

Comment: Do you actually need the array? You can always just calculate whether any given point is within or outside of the perimeter on the fly. A simple comparison function should do.

Comment: Yes I need the array for a calculation. But maybe I can first do a comparison function as you are suggesting and then build the array from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever form your array takes, the value of each location is simply a test against the functional value:

```
import math

def array_val(x, y):
    # Compute the function value for the proper angle;
    # Compare to the actual radius; return 0 or 1

    theta = math.atan(y/x)    # Adjust for proper quadrant
    r = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)
    return int(r <= (R + a * math.sin(5 * theta)))
```